# Bash script to use wget to download a file and restart a service

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 commands I want to run one after another and would like to create a script and add it to cron. My commands are:

```
wget http://browscap.org/stream?q=Full_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/browscap.ini
service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Is it possible to have it download the file, wait till it completes then run the restart script?

Comment: `service` runs after `wget` finishes in this case as it's a foreground process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the second command after your wget download completes, separate the two commands with the double ampersand `&&`

As a one-liner:

```
wget http://browscap.org/stream?q=Full_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/browscap.ini && service php7.2-fpm restart
```

The command after the double ampersand `&&` should only run if the first command (the wget download) successfully completes.

Answer (score 0):

Per the wget manual use the wait option when passing your download command (type `man wget` from CLI to see more information):

```
wget -w seconds http://browscap.org/stream?q=Full_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/browscap.ini 
service php7.2-fpm restart

or 

wget --wait=seconds http://browscap.org/stream?q=Full_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/browscap.ini
service php7.2-fpm restart
```

This will force the script to wait the specified number of seconds before proceeding with the service restart command.